# Catch UnicodeDecodeError exception while reading file line by line in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, io

Consider the following code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

In Python 3, the interpreter tries to decode the strings it reads, which might lead to exceptions like `UnicodeDecodeError`. These can of course be caught with a `try ... except` block around the whole loop, but I would like to handle them on a per-line basis.

**Question:** Is there a way to directly catch and handle exceptions for each line that is read? Hopefully without changing the simple syntax of iterating over the file too much?

Comment: why not putting the try after the open and before the "for line in f"??

Comment: Sorry if I did not clarify what I am after here: I want to be able to go on with reading the file even if one of the lines leads to an exception.

Comment: You can supply an [`errors` arg to open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). If your data is really bad, maybe you should open it in binary mode and decode each line explicitly, although that's slower.

Comment: s when you catch your exception just print it out and write "continue" - and it will without doing anything else , and continue to the next line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Pythonic way is probably to register an error handler with `codecs.register_error_handler('special', handler)` and declare it in the open function:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r', error='special') as f:
    ...
```

That way if there is an offending line, the `handler` will the called with the `UnicodeDecodeError`, and will be able to return a replacement string or re-raise the error.

If you want a more evident processing, an alternate way would be to open the file in binary mode and explicitely decode each line:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for bline in f:
        try:
            line = bline.decode()
            print(line)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            # process error
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of employing a `for` loop, you could call `next` on the file-iterator yourself and catch the `StopIteration` manually.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            line = next(f)
            # code
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # code
```

Comment: Python is free to decode in blocks (in a buffer), so this is not necessarily going to skip just single lines.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Interesting, didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

Basing on @SergeBallesta's answer. Here's the simplest thing that should work.

Instead of `open()`, use [`codecs.open(..., errors='your choice')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes). It can handle Unicode errors for you.

The [list of error handler names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) includes

> `'replace'`: "Replace with a suitable replacement marker; Python will use the official U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER for the built-in codecs on decoding, and ‘?’ on encoding"

which should handle the error and add a marker "there was something invalid here" to the text.

```
import codecs

# ...

# instead of open('filename.txt'), do:
with codecs.open('filename.txt', 'rb', 'utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
    for line in f:
        # ....
```

Answer (score -1):

Place your try-except catch inside the for loop, like so:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      try:  
        print(line)
      except:
        print("uh oh")
        # continue
```

Comment: it is probably the `for line in f:` that raises it, that's why

Comment: The `for` loop is the culprit of calling `f.__next__` so that's where the error happens. It's too late when we're inside the loop body.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I like your suggested solution in that case @timgeb.